# Where can i find gtkglextmm package for CentOS 8?

Tags: centos, yum, centos8

I'm looking for gtkglextmm, the gtk/gl C++ wrapper, for CentOS 8. On Ubuntu system, I know you can get it with `sudo apt-get install libgtkglextmm-x11-1.2-dev` but I can't find an equivalent package for `yum`.

I've tried grabbing the source and compiling that with `./configure` then with `make; make install`, but I get an error saying

> /usr/lib/libGL.so: could not read symbols: file in wrong format

I've always been weak with understanding compiler errors and how to fix them...

So, can someone either direct me to a precompiled rpm for gtkglextmm, or tell me what I need to do to compile the source?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> /usr/lib/libGL.so: could not read symbols: file in wrong format

`/usr/lib/libGL.so` is a 32bit file: i686. (64bit libraries are in  `/usr/lib64/`). Find package providing `libGL.so`: `# dnf provides */libGL.so` → `# dnf install libglvnd-devel-1:1.3.2-1.el8.x86_64`

Build example, gtkglextmm:

RHEL 8 is based on Fedora 28: Get the source package https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/28/Everything/source/tree/Packages/g/gtkglextmm-1.2.0-28.fc28.src.rpm .... to check what else "BuildRequires" is missing: `# dnf builddep gtkglextmm-1.2.0-28.fc28.src.rpm`.

Missing files from Fedora 28 https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/28/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/ : pangox-compat.x86_64, pangox-compat-devel.x86_64, etc.

```
# dnf install ./pangox-compat-*
# dnf install ./gtkglext-libs-1.2.0-32.fc28.x86_64.rpm
# dnf install ./gtkglext-devel-1.2.0-32.fc28.x86_64.rpm
```

Get other 'BuildRequires'
`# dnf builddep gtkglextmm-1.2.0-28.fc28.src.rpm` : Total package count installed for gtkglextmm, including the four "fc28" and their dependencies was **62** packages!

Install the SRPM to /home/name/rpmbuild/: `$ rpm -Uvh gtkglextmm-1.2.0-28.fc28.src.rpm`

Build gtkglextmm packages:

```
$ cd rpmbuild/SPECS/
$ rpmbuild -bb gtkglextmm.spec
.
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/gtkglextmm-1.2.0-28.el8.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/gtkglextmm-devel-1.2.0-28.el8.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/gtkglextmm-debugsource-1.2.0-28.el8.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/gtkglextmm-debuginfo-1.2.0-28.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

... So then you can either install the new el8 packages, or the Fedora 28 packages `gtkglextmm.x86_64, gtkglextmm-devel.x86.64` from
https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/28/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/g/